# Difference of Loading dll by direct calling Loadlibrary function and by dll Injection method: Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, dll-injection

I am developing an injection project by Delphi.
Inject dll includes a form that has several events like as formcreate, timer, formdestroy etc....
dll project codes are like below...

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  Forms,
  Classes,
  UnitClient in 'UnitClient.pas' {ClientForm},

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.CreateForm(TClientForm, ClientForm);
end.
```

When I call LoadLibrary function for loading this dll in a main exe project, then it works well (show the ClientForm and all events of dll works good)

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hmod: HMODULE;
begin
  hmod := LoadLibrary(PWideChar(Format('%s%s',[ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName),'inj.dll'])));
  if hmod <> 0 then
    Caption := 'Loading successful'
  else
    Caption := 'Loading failed';

end;
```

But when I use injection method for loading dll by third process, then the Clientform appeared for a few millseconds, and then disappeared. all events of the dll form don't work too.

Below is Injection code.

```
function InjectDLL(const dwPID: DWORD; {$IFDEF UNICODE} DLLPath: PWideChar
  {$ELSE} DLLPath: PAnsiChar {$ENDIF}): Integer;
const
  Kernel32 = 'kernel32.dll';
var
  dwThreadID: Cardinal;
  hProc, hThread, hKernel: THandle;
  BytesToWrite, BytesWritten: NativeUInt; 
  pRemoteBuffer, pLoadLibrary: Pointer;
begin
  hProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or
      PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_WRITE or PROCESS_VM_READ, False,
    dwPID);
  if hProc = 0 then
    Exit(0);
  try
    BytesToWrite := SizeOf(WideChar) * (Length(DLLPath) + 1);
    pRemoteBuffer := VirtualAllocEx(hProc, nil, BytesToWrite, MEM_COMMIT,
      PAGE_READWRITE);
    if pRemoteBuffer = nil then
      Exit(0);
    try

      if WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pRemoteBuffer, DLLPath, BytesToWrite,
        BytesWritten) = False then
        Exit(0);
{$REGION 'Check for UNICODE'}
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
      hKernel := GetModuleHandleW(Kernel32);
      pLoadLibrary := GetProcAddress(hKernel, 'LoadLibraryW');
{$ELSE}
      hKernel := GetModuleHandleA(Kernel32);
      pLoadLibrary := GetProcAddress(hKernel, 'LoadLibraryA');
{$ENDIF}
{$ENDREGION}
      hThread := CreateRemoteThread(hProc, nil, 0, pLoadLibrary, pRemoteBuffer,
        0, dwThreadID);
      try
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(hThread);
      end;
    finally
      VirtualFreeEx(hProc, pRemoteBuffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProc);
  end;
  Exit(1);
end;
```

I confirmed the dll is correctly injected to third process by process explorer.
How should I do for abnormal working of dll form by injection method?
Please give advice,help,

Comment: In main.exe project, load the library from a secondary thread. Then you'll be comparing.

Comment: Pretty unlikely that you are going to be able to inject your UI into a background thread. I'd give it up as a bad job and find a proper solution for your problem. Whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject a second UI like this.  To solve this problem, create a new window and put your UI in that, then when you inject your DLL a second window will pop up with your form in it.